# Function to create tree of words

Tags: python, string, tree

I want to create a function that takes a string. From the string provided, I want to take one letter from the string and add it to the string in every position from the first position to the last.

I would like to keep doing this until I have a word that makes complete sense (I have a dictionary of words that "make sense" that I will check against)

Here is an example of what I want (starts from 'posta' [sorry for the italian], and decends into posta-sposta-esposta-sposata-spossata... and so on):

```
posta
    sposta
        esposta
        sposata
            spossata
            spostata
        spostai
            spostati
                spostarti
                spostasti
            spostavi
                spostarvi
    posata
        sposata
            spossata
            spostata
    posita
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what your goal is.  It is not clear how you go from the one work 'posta' to having the multiple words with '-' between them and then having the spaces.


Also, what have you tried so far?  What results did it give you?  What does your code look like so far?  If you have been working on this for a week certainly you have something to share with us.

Comment: it's exercize i have to do for my course,i want to start like with a string like"apple" and using or "a" or "p" or "l" or "e" with "apple" i make "papple" if is a english word, i have a dictionary with i can check so i want to create all the combination and check if that combination is a real word e add in to a tree of words.now is more clear??

Comment: just this but it's wrong but is't something liek this:

Comment: def permute(seq):
    
    if len(seq) <= 1:
        perms = [seq]
    else:
        perms = []
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            
            sub = permute(seq[:i]+seq[i+1:]) 
            for p in sub:     
                perms.append(seq[i:i+1]+p+seq[i])

Comment: You should post the code that you've tried and doesn't work, and why you think it doesn't work.

Comment: i i think it's because i dont really understand how iteration works

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import string

#This is your list of valid words
words = ['niente', 'sposta', 'esposta', 'sposata', 'spossata', 'spostata',
'spostai', 'spostati', 'spostarti', 'spostasti', 'spostavi', 'spostarvi',
'posata', 'sposata', 'spossata', 'spostata', 'posita']

class Tree:
    def __init__ (self, payload):
        self.payload = payload
        self.children = []

    def __iadd__ (self, child):
        if child not in self.children:
            self.children.append (child)
        return self

    def pprint (self, indent = 0):
        print (' ' * indent + self.payload)
        for child in self.children:
            child.pprint (indent + 2)

    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return self.payload == other.payload

def expand (word):
    node = Tree (word)
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase: #or whatever caracters you need, maybe also è, ì, etc
        for p in range (len (word) + 1):
            candidate = word [:p] + c + word [p:]
            if candidate in words:
                node += expand (candidate)
    return node

a = expand ('posta')
a.pprint ()
```

For example, if as valid words I take my '/usr/share/dict/words' and I expand "arm", this yields:

```
arm
  farm
    farms
  harm
    charm
      charms
    harem
      harems
    harms
      charms
      harems
  arms
    farms
    harms
      charms
      harems
    warms
      swarms
  warm
    swarm
      swarms
    warms
      swarms
  army
```

Comment: Updated code to omit duplicates which erase from various forms of insertation, e.g. `sposata -> spoSsata and sposSata`.

Comment: i know i cant say thanks but now i check if works and i want to say thanks to you!!